# Replacing C++ STL output iterator with a Python generator

Tags: c++, python, generics, boost, python-3.x

Python doesn't have a builtin equivalent of OutputIterator; in particular, builtin or standard library containers do not support any generic interface that allows client code to send data to them without knowing the specific container type.

According to [@Steven Rumbalski's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707418/why-are-collections-not-handled-uniformly-in-python#comment3915694_3707535) and [@Glenn Maynard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3707535/336527), this is not usually a problem because a function that in C++ would have taken an OutputIterator argument, in python would be simply written as a generator.

Normally, I have no problem using generators, and never felt I needed an OutputIterator in Python. However, in this one case, I'm stuck.

I am re-implementing in Python some of the algorithms from the Boost Graph Library. A typical graph traversal algorithm, say `depth_first_search`, takes as a parameter a "visitor" object. The visitor is essentially a bunch of callback functions that the traversal algorithm calls as it encounters different events in its execution (e.g., discovering a new vertex, examining an edge, etc.). In C++, I can have one or several of these callback functions send data to the OutputIterator objects that the visitor object obtained at its initialization from the client code. (For instance, that's precisely how `topological_sort` is implemented: it takes an OutputIterator, passes it to a `dfs_visitor` object, the visitor object then "monitors" the event `finished_vertex` and sends the vertexes it receives to the specified OutputIterator. Of course, more complex cases require multiple OutputIterator objects and multiple callback functions.)

How do I achieve the same with Python generators?

I need to somehow send data, in the generator "style", from `depth_first_search` to multiple designated data consumers. I just can't figure out how to do it. (I'm using Python 3.3.)

Answer (score 1):

Can you just pass callback functions?

```
def depth_first_search(some_args, on_edge=lambda e:None, on_vertex=lambda v:None):
    ...
    on_edge(some_edge)
    on_vertex(some_vertex)

def edge_handler(e):
    print "E", e

def vertex_handler(v):
    print "V", v

depth_first_search(..., on_edge=edge_handler, on_vertex=vertex_handler)
```

Or yield a destination:

```
def depth_first_search(some_args, on_edge=lambda e:None, on_vertex=lambda v:None):
    ...
    yield "edge", some_edge
    yield "vertex", some_vertex

for t, value in depth_first_search(...):
    if t == 'edge':
        # ...
    elif t == 'vertex':
        # ...
```

Comment: If you merely want to print each vertex, you can. In a realistic scenario, however, you need to send the vertexes received by `vertex_handler` further down the data processing pipe (e.g., to process it with some other generator function). Thus, `edge_handler` needs to be a generator itself; but I don't see how, since its caller uses it to push the data into it, rather than receive the data from it.

Comment: @Max: I'm not sure I understand the goal here. Could you write some minimal C++ code you want to be able to convert to python?

Comment: @max: I'm taking wild guesses at what your end goal is. In some cases, text messages would be fine. It depends how independant edge and vertex processing are

Comment: Yes, you're right it's a reasonable approach. I was looking for something slightly different, though; and I failed to explain it clearly. I'll show an example shortly.

Answer (score 1):

The [`generator.send`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-iterator-methods) method does what you want here, I think:

```
def depth_first_search(some_args, edge_consumer, vertex_consumer):
    # start the generators
    next(edge_consumer)
    next(vertex_consumer)

    ...
    edge_consumer.send(some_edge)
    vertex_consumer.send(some_vertex)

    ...
    # this raises GeneratorExit at the `yield` in the generator
    edge_consumer.close()
    vertex_consumer.close()

def edge_handler():
    while True:
        e = yield
        print "E", e

def vertex_handler():
    while True:
        v = yield
        print "V", v

depth_first_search(..., edge_handler(), vertex_handler())
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would work, but what about using a library like multimethods to implement a multiple-dispatch function to do what you need? My Internet is having DNS problems so I can't look up the syntax, so you'll be getting pseudocode instead of real Python, but here's a general idea of what I'm talking about:

```
def send_to(data, consumer):
    workfunc = dispatch(type(consumer))
    workfunc(data, consumer)

def send_to_list(data, consumer):
    consumer.append(data)

def send_to_set(data, consumer):
    consumer.add(data)

def send_to_file_obj(data, consumer):
    consumer.write(data)
```

Some plumbing would be needed to hook up the work functions to the dispatch function, of course, and that's what I can't actually look up right now since my DNS is down. (StackOverflow, fortunately, is still in my browser cache). So I'm afraid this answer is long on generalities and short on specifics, but hopefully it will at least point you in a helpful direction.